# Why do I have this error whenever I insert Data to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, newline

I have this problem whenever I insert my integer value to my database it looks like this

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1366</p><p>Incorrect integer value: '
11' for column 'code' at row 1</p><p>INSERT INTO `company`(`code`, `Name`) 
                             VALUES('\n11', 'John')
```

my code is in a span and my name is an input type. is there a way to remove the \n in the values?

ADDITIONAL CODE

```
function insert_new_name()
        {

        $code = $this->input->get('code');
        $name = $this->input->get('name');

        $sSQL = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE code = ? or Name = ? AND `show` = 1"  ;
        $result = $this->db->query($sSQL, array($code, $name));
            if($result->num_rows() != 0)
                {
                 return json_encode('error');
                }
            else
                {
                $sSQL = "INSERT INTO `company`(`code`, `Name`) 
                         VALUES(?, ?) ";
                $result = $this->db->query($sSQL, array($code, $name));
                $id = $this->db->insert_id();
                $sSQLdisplay = "SELECT * FROM Name where id = '$id' ";
                $resultdisplay = $this->db->query($sSQLdisplay);
                $data = array();
                $row = $resultdisplay->row();
                    $data[] = Array($row->id);
                    $data[] = Array($row->code);
                    $data[] = Array($row->Name);
                    $data[] = Array('');                        
                    $data[] = Array(''); 
                $resultdisplay->free_result();
                return json_encode($data);  
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the calling code look like?

Comment: Please don't edit the title with solved. The fact that you've accepted an answer indicates the question has been answered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove the new line character from that value before binding it to your query:

```
$code = trim($this->input->get('code'));
```

Comment: You need to parse the input value and make sure that an integer was sent. If a user enters a non integer, they will be shown a confusing sql error. This check needs to happen regardless of what checks you are running client side.

Answer (score 2):

Well it looks like you are trying to insert a string `'\n11'` into a field that requires an integer. You will need to strip out non-numeric characters from the `code` value that you want to insert and parse it to an integer, to make the following command:

```
INSERT INTO `company`(`code`, `Name`) VALUES(11, 'John')
```

Answer (score 1):

for integer value best option is use intval() to convert any string or null value in integer value

$code = intval($this->input->get('code'));// you will get either 0 or greater then 0

Examples :

1. $this->input->get('code')  this has value \n11 
   $code = intval($this->input->get('code')); //11
2. $this->input->get('code')  this has value abc11
   $code = intval($this->input->get('code')); //11
3. $this->input->get('code')  this has value abc
   $code = intval($this->input->get('code')); //0

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\n` char from `code` field value, `code` field looks like integer

```
INSERT INTO `company`(`code`, `Name`) 
                             VALUES('11', 'John')
```

please user `trim`function,

Like this

```
$code = trim($this->input->get('code'), " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```

OR

```
$code = trim($this->input->get('code'));
```

Comment: I dont have \n in my field value Girish, it's just show up wheneve I like to insert my values

Comment: @user3213861 can you please add code in question where you are using insert query

Comment: posted my query  Girish Jangid